# Why am I getting an "ImportError: No module named threaded" message?

Tags: python, serialization, importerror, pyserial

I'm trying to run one of the examples from pyserial, [tcp-ip-serial-bridge](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/examples.html#tcp-ip-serial-bridge) on my raspberry pi 2.  When I run it, I get "ImportError: No module named threaded" on line 12 "import serial.threaded".  All of my searching for this on stack overflow has shown many others using serial.threaded with no issue, asking questions about other import errors. Any ideas?

I saw some other similar (but different) errors were caused by things having slightly different names in newer versions of python, so if that's the case: does anyone know what serial.threaded is now called?

Thanks

Comment: Did you [install `pyserial`](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial#installation) first?

Comment: please add the python version you are using in the tags, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from terminal on raspberry pi run:

```
sudo pip install pyserial
sudo pip install pyserial --upgrade
```

then try your code again

Comment: running this yielded my discovery of the need to upgrade pyserial.

Comment: good to  know..ill add your solution to my answer for future viewers

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update pyserial.

```
pip install pyserial --upgrade
```